# pg_dump: too many command-line arguments when calling from cmd

Tags: cmd, backup, psql, pg-dump

Im trying to make a backup in a folder C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\proba where "proba" is the name of backup file.

My command looks like this:

```
pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\proba
```

and then i get an error: " pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\proba") "

But, when I write a command like:

```
pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres >C:\radni_sati_backup\radni_sati_proba
```

Everything works, and I get that "radni_sati_proba" file in the directory as I listed in command.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was:

```
pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\proba
```

needs to be like this:

```
pg_dump -h 192.168.130.240 -p 5433 -U postgres  -F c  postgres > "C:\Users\Marko Petričević\Documents\Radni_sati_Backup\proba"
```

Problem was the space in path.